# Why am I not able to access the meanings API?

Tags: javascript, html, calculator, calculation

I am trying to access the "meaning" from this API link, but every time it does not return anything? API link:https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/hello

```
<div class="word-img"></div>
<button class="word-btn">Click Here</button>

const WORD_URL = "https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/hello";
const word = document.querySelector(".word-img");
async function addNewWord() {
const promise = await fetch(WORD_URL);
const processedResponse = await promise.json();
let text = document.createElement("h1");

text.innerHTML = processedResponse.meanings.definitions.definition;
text.style.fontSize = "25px";
text.style.color = "blue";
word.appendChild(text);
console.log(text); }

document.querySelector(".word-btn").addEventListener("click", addNewWord);
```

Comment: You get back an array. But you don't access that array. To the get first `definition` of `definitions` of the first `meaning` in `meanings` you need to use: `processedResponse[0].meanings[0].definitions[0].definition`. You should get some errors in the console doing what you are doing.

Comment: try replacing text.innerHTML = processedResponse.meanings.definitions.definition;
this line with 


text.innerHTML = processedResponse.data.meanings.definitions.definition;

Comment: Thank you, I had figured that out later.